# VirtualBox installation failure on Windows

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

When I try to install `VirtualBox 4.1.6`, at the end of the installation it says `Rolling back action`, removes all previously installed files and then the installation gives me the following message: `Oracle VM VirtualBox 4.1.6 setup ended prematurely because of an error. Your system has not been modified. To install this program at a later time, run Setup wizard again.`

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Better off on superuser (but just a hrads-up they may ask for more clarification on what it is you're asking + installer logfiles etc)

Comment: And what does it do or say when you run it again?

Comment: If vbox uses Windows Installer, then there should be a log file somewhere: search for files created/modified around the time the install failed. This will hopefully contain more detail: if not the actual error, at leas an indication of the step at which the error occured.

Comment: Have already any previous version of Virtualbox? Uninstall it and then try installing the new version again. It won't delete your virtual machines or so.

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions here: http://dottech.org/101997/how-to-uninstall-virtualbox-drivers-on-windows/

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46054425/persistent-installerror-with-virtualbox and https://superuser.com/questions/930864/how-to-install-virtualbox-on-windows-10-host