# How to Install Virtualbox on Windows 10 host?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10-preview

I am trying to install virtual box v4.3.28-100309 on a Windows 10 Host.
The windows 10 insider preview installed is build 10130. When I try to install the virtualbox exe I am getting the following error:

`Status: Rolling Back action:`

[image]

And after this I get a dialog box:

`Oracle VM Virtualbox 4.3.28 Setup Wizard ended prematurely`

[image]

I am running Windows 10 on a i5-core processor with 8GB Ram machine and not a virtual machine.

Comment: don't you have Hyper-V to use?

Comment: 5.0.1 isn't working, too :-/

Comment: 5.0.4 still the same issue... have you fond any solution?

Comment: @MartinPfeffer Have you found an issue in the latest version (ver. 5.0.10) yet?

Comment: Nevermind, I have asked a new question, about my comment, here: http://superuser.com/questions/1005264/installing-virtualbox-5-0-10-on-the-latest-version-of-windows-10-ver-1511-105#1005281

Comment: @Kevdog777 I am pissed by windows 10. Right now I use Linux Mint 17.2, rock solid, 100% stable, not a single issue, and its blazing fast. I can only recommend to switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install VirtualBox 4 on Windows 10 (Note it doesn't work for the new VB 5) by disabling Bridge Networking during the installation. To be more precise I succeeded with VirtualBox-4.3.28-100309-Win.exe installed under Windows 10 x64 Build 10074 with no bridge networking.

Latest version of Windows 10 seems to allow installation of both VirtualBox 4 and VirtualBox 5. Still I found some issues initializing the network adapter through Vagrant.

There is a VB defect ticket here related https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14040 . If the network adapter cannot be properly initialized use the following executable https://www.virtualbox.org/attachment/ticket/14040/VBox-Win10-fix-14040.exe. You have to run it as administrator during the VM startup after which it work properly.

Comment: Thanks, I was also able to install it by disabling the Bridge networking but what I was looking at was a solution with Bridge networking as my Samba installed on Ubuntu is not accessible by the host on NAT

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy this to notepad and save as something.reg

> ```
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Network]
> "MaxNumFilters"="0x20"
> ```

2. Double-click on the file to modify the registry
3. Open the command prompt with windows key + <kbd>X</kbd>
4. Go to the folder were you downloaded the .exe installer using `cd yourfolderpath`
5. Extract the .msi from the .exe

   > `VirtualBox-5.1.8-111374-Win.exe /extract`
6. Go to the folder with the extracted .msi

   > `cd C:/users/replace_here_with_username/appdata/local/temp/virtualbox`
7. Run this to install: (64bit)

> ```
> msiexec /i VirtualBox-5.1.8-r111374-MultiArch_amd64.msi /L*vx VirtualBox-5.1.8-install.log /QB TARGETDIR="C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox" ADDLOCAL=VBoxNetworkFlt
> ```

or (32-bit)

```
msiexec /i VirtualBox-5.1.8-r111374-MultiArch_x86.msi /L*vx VirtualBox-5.1.8-install.log /QB TARGETDIR="C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox" ADDLOCAL=VBoxNetworkFlt
```

8. Go to the folder Oracle in Program files to open virtualbox

It might be possible that you have to run this procedure as administrator.
Based on [this link](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11349?cversion=0&cnum_hist=15)

Comment: When ever I execute the command, I've got a Help text open in a GUI but the installer seams to ignore me. Any ideas why ?

Comment: did you try as admin