# Installing VirtualBox 5.0.10 on the latest version of Windows 10 (ver. 1511, 10586)

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10

This question is very similar to: [How to Install Virtualbox on Windows 10 host?](https://superuser.com/questions/930864/how-to-install-virtualbox-on-windows-10-host#comment1343090_930864).

But will VirtualBox 5.0.10 run fine on the latest version of Windows 10 (ver. 1511, 10586)?

I am running Windows 7 64bit on my host machine with VB 5.0.10 - but am going to upgrade, but don't want to lose my machines (1.25 TB worth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Virtual Box 5.0.10 with Windows 10.0 (Pro), build 10240 and it works perfectly

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for reassuring me! I have a windows 10 VM, so will double check it, after I have upgraded to Windows 10 pro (build 10586).

Comment: Yeah will do, when I have double checked the answer and if it has worked. :)