# Installation of VirtualBox 5.0.x on 64-bit Windows 10 Build 10586: error code 2203

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, bridged

I had a hard time installing VirtualBox 5.0.x on my 64-bit Windows 10 Build Version 10586. I did read [How to Install VirtualBox on Windows 10 host?](https://superuser.com/questions/930864/how-to-install-virtualbox-on-windows-10-host), but it did not help. Actually I don't know how to disable bridged networking on Windows 10 either. (It seems that there is no bridged networking now on my connection). When I installed VirtualBox, I encountered this error.

[image]

I searched for hours on the Internet to find a solution, but I'm still stuck. I really need VirtualBox now. Please help me out.

Comment: Hi folks, I've realized VirtualBox does not support this build version of Windows 10 yet. So I just migrated to Ubuntu to install VirtualBox. Thanks all ;)